# Semantic UI in Visual Studio - How to kick off gulp tasks in subfolders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, gulp, semantic-ui

**Scenario:**
Visual Studio 2015 with an MVC 6 (I mean MVC Core 1.0) project. I used bower to install Semantic UI, but I don't think the question is specific to Semantic.

**Issue:**
There is a gulp file at the root of the project which I can use to do gulp stuff - but Semantic comes with it's own gulp files in `/wwwroot/css/lib/semantic-ui` which you can use to customize the themes with your own overrides. So I need to be able to run that gulpfile's tasks when I make changes.

**Things I've tried**

1. I see a couple of gulp functions that might kick off tasks in other files, but I'm not clear which function is best, or really what I need to require in the root file before I call the semantic gulp file. (I'm new to gulp)
2. I tried using the Task Runner Explorer and Mad's Web Compiler to compile the semantic file manually - which would be fine at this point - but I'm also new to LESS and while it appears to compile it throws some errors about missing variables (which don't appear to be missing) which I can't debug. That's probably a separate question, but trying to give all the background.

When I read posts online they mostly assume you are either running from command line or doing everything in the gulpfile in the root of the project. I'd prefer to keep everything within Visual Studio and just refer to the gulp file that comes with the Semantic package. Of course, I'm new to gulp and LESS, so maybe that's just what I think I'd prefer - I'm open to other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this gulp task to gulp.js of your root file :

```
function runTask(command, tasks) {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawnSync;
    var path = '/www/root/css/lib/semantic-ui'; //or the relative path
    process.chdir(path);

    child = spawn(command, tasks); 
    process.chdir('../../../'); //bring it back to the directory from where you are running the gulp task

}

gulp.task('semantic', function(){
    return runTask('gulp', ['build']); //add the gulp tasks here in the array
});
```

Comment: > cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\code\RPS\src\MyProject" --color --gulpfile "C:\code\RPS\src\MyProject\Gulpfile.js" semanticProcess terminated with code 1.[20:48:46] Using gulpfile C:\code\RPS\src\MyProject\Gulpfile.js[20:48:46] Starting 'semantic'...[20:48:46] 'semantic' errored after 171 μs[20:48:46] Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory    at process.chdir (C:\code\RPS\src\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:14:9)    at process.chdir (C:\code\RPS\src\MyProject\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:14:9)    at runTask

Comment: thanks for replying - when I try it I get the response in the comment above.

also - removed the extra slash in www/root

Comment: you have to put the relative path here, relative to your current working directory